# Detecting Eject/Insert of Removeable Media

Tags: c#, wmi

I am working on a project in which I need to be able to detect when a CD or a USB drive is inserted or removed. I found some source code that was supposed to do this very thing, however, nothing seems to happen when I insert or eject a CD.

Could someone please verify that the source is correct, and give me any pointers as to what I may have done wrong here?

```
public class MyWindow
{
    ManagementEventWatcher w;

    private void MyWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        WqlEventQuery query = new WqlEventQuery("__InstanceCreationEvent", new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1), @"TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_LogicalDisk' and TargetInstance.DriveType = 2");
        ConnectionOptions opt = new ConnectionOptions();
        opt.EnablePrivileges = true;

        ManagementScope ms = new ManagementScope("root\\CIMV2", opt);

        w = new ManagementEventWatcher(ms, query);

        w.EventArrived += new EventArrivedEventHandler(w_EventArrived);
        w.Start();
    }

    private void w_EventArrived(object sender, EventArrivedEventArgs e)
    {
        PropertyData pd = e.NewEvent.Properties["TargetInstance"];
    }
}
```

When I set a breakpoint on the "PropertyData pd = ..." line, it never gets hit when I eject/insert a CD. Since I've not messed with this at all, and all of the examples I've seen online simply cite this same source code (with minor variations)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
using System.Management;

public void networkDevice()
{
    try
    {
        WqlEventQuery q = new WqlEventQuery();
        q.EventClassName = "__InstanceModificationEvent";
        q.WithinInterval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
        q.Condition = @"TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_LogicalDisk' and TargetInstance.DriveType = 5";

        ConnectionOptions opt = new ConnectionOptions();
        opt.EnablePrivileges = true;
        opt.Authority = null;
        opt.Authentication = AuthenticationLevel.Default;
        //opt.Username = "Administrator";
        //opt.Password = "";
        ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope("\\root\\CIMV2", opt);

        ManagementEventWatcher watcher = new ManagementEventWatcher(scope, q);
        watcher.EventArrived += new EventArrivedEventHandler(watcher_EventArrived);
        watcher.Start();
    }
    catch (ManagementException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
}

void watcher_EventArrived(object sender, EventArrivedEventArgs e)
{
    ManagementBaseObject wmiDevice = (ManagementBaseObject)e.NewEvent["TargetInstance"];
    string driveName = (string)wmiDevice["DeviceID"];
    Console.WriteLine(driveName);
    Console.WriteLine(wmiDevice.Properties["VolumeName"].Value);
    Console.WriteLine((string)wmiDevice["Name"]);
    if (wmiDevice.Properties["VolumeName"].Value != null)
        Console.WriteLine("CD has been inserted");
    else
        Console.WriteLine("CD has been ejected");
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked... I'm a little confused as to why though. I had tried `...DriveType = 5` too, and the only other difference I see is the `\\` before `root\\CIMV2`. PEBCAK mebbe? Only other thing I ask is that the formatting on your answer be fixed so it's readable. Thanks again so very much!