# Detect removeable media

Tags: c#, windows, media, detect

I want to detect when a removal media is inserted or removed from the PC and I have read many threads of how to do it.

Reading other threads and pages gives essential two methods

1. Override WinProc method
2. Make SQL query

There is a FileSystemWatcher class, is there reallý not a "DriveSystemWatcher" or something ?

Also, if I try the "SQL" approach it can not compile the program becosue it can not resolve "ManagementEventWatcher", even if I do

using System;

using System.Management;

Help would be appreciated

Regards Stefan.

Comment: Have you at least added a reference to `System.Management.dll` to your project if you wish to use classes from `System.Management`?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "override WinProc method" *or* how you would use Sql to detect a media insertion.  Regardless, this seems to be a dupe...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detecting Eject/Insert of Removeable Media](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1662794/detecting-eject-insert-of-removeable-media)

Comment: @Dan I think the OP means "querying WMI" when Sql is mentioned???

Comment: The "override WinProc" is when trapping low level windows messages manually
The "SQL thing" is @"TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_LogicalDisk' and TargetInstance.DriveType = 5";
Looks to me some simplified sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use classes from `System.Management` (so that you can query WMI) you need to add a reference to `System.Management.dll` to your project.

The following describes an approach using WMI when you've done this:

[Detecting Eject/Insert of Removeable Media](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1662794/detecting-eject-insert-of-removeable-media)

Comment: Yes, I had forgott to incldue "System.Management.dll", thanks for the tip.

Comment: However when I implement the code in "Detecting Eject/Insert of Removeable Media" it does not trap the usb memory stick, even if I do "TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_LogicalDisk' and TargetInstance.DriveType = 5 or TargetInstance.DriveType = 2"

Comment: @user765903 HTH - You need to add your comment to that question.